# Why doesn't appsync customer domain support active/active multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, aws-appsync

I am thinking to setup Appsync in two regions and use Route53 routing policy to route traffic to different region. By reading this doc: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/multi-region-deployment-aws-appsync-dynamodb-tables/

It says

`If an Active/Active configuration is desired with a single custom domain, our solution in this blog post can be extended by putting an Amazon API Gateway regional API in front of AWS AppSync in each Region, and use latency-based routing in Amazon Route 53 to direct traffic to the backend with the lowest latency.`

What I don't understand is that why I need to build a API gateway for each appsync. What is the fundamental issue with Appsync about supporting active/active domains. In other words, how it is different between API gateway and Appsync in terms of custom domain?